# Why are these two regexes not the same?

Tags: regex, pcre

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955584/regex-for-starting-string-with-two-options) and it got me thinking about emulating variable-width lookbehinds.

Doesn't work:

```
(?:(?<=<\/)|(?<=<))[^ >]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/1wQz5E/1/

Works:

```
(?:(?<=<\/)|(?<=<))[^ >\/]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/1wQz5E/2

The expectation is for the closing tag's forward slash to be omitted from the match.

I am trying to wrap my head around why my first example fails to behave as desired.

---

Source string:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has been discussed in some threads here. The regex engine parses the string from left to right. People keep forgetting this important bit. `(?<=<)` gets matched even when `(?<=<\/)` is, so `/` ends up in the match. Since you added it to the negated character class in the second regex, it does not match `/`.

Comment: The forward slash isn't part of the negated character class so therefor it can be matches against the 2nd nested positive lookbehind (would be my reading) =)

Comment: You first regex is equal to `(?<=<\/|<)[^ >]+`. When the input is `</a>`, the position after `<` is found first, then `[^ >]+` consumes `/` and all what it can.

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I did notice that's what's happening. I was expecting the left side of the boolean to have precedence when matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does the boolean operator not give higher precedence to the left side?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I see what you mean but if a match fails (as per the first lookbehind) I'd like to believe that the engine will try to continue matching other options to see if it has to capture the forward slash or not (untill all options fail).

Comment: It does, but it is not a consuming pattern. What matches first, wins. The position right after `<` in `</a>` comes first, not the position right after `</`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: `(?<=</|<(?!/))[^ >]+` would work fine since it will discard `/` after `<` in 2nd alternation

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057983/javascript-regex-unable-to-remove-leading-spaces-in-lookahead-group-in-a-multi/63060061#63060061) is about the same thing: alternation, or a `+`/`*`/`{1,x}` quantifiers at the end of the lookbehind patterns match the minimal amount of chars.

Comment: The assertion is to the left. When it encounters `<` in `</title>` the second assertion is true. When trying to  match it can not, due to `[^ >\/]` that does not allow `/`, then it moves to the next position because there is no more of the pattern to process.. Next thing is `</` which is true for the first assertion, and `[^ >\/]+` can match the following chars. There is no precedence, at the current position, only 1 of the assertions can be true.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think "lookbehind patterns match the minimal amount of chars" is the explanation I was waiting for as it is the behavior exhibited by the regex. I guess I was just looking to verify that booleans are not left-to-right but rather fewest matched.

Comment: @AndyLester Although my sample uses HTML to show the point, I am not interested in parsing HTML. My question is about variable-width lookbehinds. Please do not tag HTML as it tends to attract a predisposition for downvotes, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your first regex can be shortened to `(?<=<\/|<)[^ >]+`, it is easier to work with shorter patterns.

Keep in mind, **the regex engine parses the string from left to right.** The `(?<=<\/|<)` lookbehind matches a *location* that is immediately preceded with `</` or `<`, i.e. a location right after `<` or `</`.

When the input is `</a>`, the position after `<` is found with the `(?<=<\/|<)` pattern first (as it is more to the left than the position after `</`), and then `[^ >]+` consumes `/` and all what it can match, and `[^ >]+` *can* match `/` and `<`, all the chars that the lookbehind pattern matches.

What matches first in an alternation wins, [this rule](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager) is not broken here, just the alternation happens to be in a non-consuming pattern here, and that bit should also be kept in mind.

**A rule of thumb** here is: alternation, or unknown length quantifiers like `+`/`*`/`{1,x}` *at the end of the lookbehind patterns* that are immediately followed with a consuming pattern that also matches those trailing lookbehind patterns, make the lookbehind patterns match the fewest chars, and the subsequent consuming patterns tend to start grabbing content as early as they can.

In such cases, **the safest solution** is to use *consuming* patterns instead of infinite length lookbehind together with a *capturing group* to grab the requied part of the match:

```js
(?:<\/|<)([^ >]+)
<\/?([^ >]+)
```

Or, in PCRE/Onigmo/PyPi Python regex, you may also use `\K`:

```
<\/?\K[^ >]+
```

Here, the non-capturing `(?:<\/|<)` group or `<\/?` pattern will match and consume `<` or `</`, and the `([^ >]+)` capturing group will yield the expected substring since it won't have a chance to grab the text right after `<`. `\K` just omits all text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer, so the only text returned is the one matched with `[^ >]+`.

However, in this case, you can also solve the problem with the lookbehinds by requiring the first char matched with `[^ >]+` to be a char other than `/`:

```js
(?<=<|</)[^ >/][^ >]*
```

So, basically unrolling `[^ >/]+` with `[^ >/][^ >]*`.

Comment: I must be going crazy, I thought lookbehinds were supposed to be fixed width. Why doesn't `<\/|<` violate that? Am I getting confused with Python?...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus This is much more confusing: in PCRE, you can have alternatives of different lengths granted they are of known length. In Python and Boost, they should be all of the same length.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I added a **rule of thumb** passage, I hope the wording is now clear.

Comment: The subtleties can be maddening. Thank you for your time and answer

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ok, I think I finished, just added solutions. I would not use the `(?<=<|</)[^ >/]+` pattern, it is OK in the tag context, but it is not universal. Well, ``(?<=<|</)[^ >/][^ >]*`` will work though, but makes it longer.

Comment: Thank you. It's further interesting that `(?<=<\/|<)` is legal in PCRE but `(?<=<\/?)` is not. I guess since the former is alternation instead of a quantifier the engine is able to handle it through a supported channel.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It is like this: PCRE only makes an exception for literal patterns to be of different lengths in different alternatives. It does not even allow a nested alternation group with alternatives of different lengths, or even a backreference to a capturing group enclosing a literal (and thus of known length) value. `(?<=b|(?:ca|ada))a`, `(?<=b|(c)\1)a` are invalid. However, if the alternation or backreference are in a lookahead nested in the lookbehind, it is allowed (as in `(?<=b|(c)(?!\1))\w`). PCRE does not support `*` and `+` and `{n,m}` (where `m` is bigger than `n`) in lookbehinds.

Answer (score 2):

For the current examples, in this pattern `(?:(?<=<\/)|(?<=<))[^ >]+` looking back from the current position, what is directly to the left can be only either  `</` or `<` so only 1 of the assertions can be true at the same time.

When it encounters `<` in `</title>` the second assertion is true. When trying to match it can not, due to `[^ >\/]` that does not allow `/`, then it moves to the next position because there is no more of the pattern to process.

Next thing is `</` which is true for the first assertion, and `[^ >\/]+` can match the following chars.

So the reason it does not yield the expected matches is because in this pattern `(?:(?<=<\/)|(?<=<))[^ >]+` the lookbehind is the same, but the negated character class `[^ >]+` **can** match the `/` in `</title>`